# Specify Output Directory for SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation

Tags: sql-server, bootstrapper

I am trying to install `SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2` as part of my `Bootstrapper Installer` created for my server components.

By default SQL Server is installed in C drive. How should I instruct the installer to install it in user picked drive.

Here is my code:

```
<PackageGroup Id="SQLServerExpress">
  <ExePackage InstallCommand='/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True" /INSTANCEID="CCSERVER" /ACTION="Install" /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /HIDECONSOLE /HELP="False" /INDICATEPROGRESS="True" /ERRORREPORTING="False" /SQMREPORTING="False" /INSTANCENAME="CCSERVER" /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual" /ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" /ISSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" /ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" /ASCOLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS" /ASDATADIR="Data" /ASLOGDIR="Log" /ASBACKUPDIR="Backup" /ASTEMPDIR="Temp" /ASCONFIGDIR="Config" /ASPROVIDERMSOLAP="1" /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" /FILESTREAMLEVEL="0" /ENABLERANU="False" /SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True" /TCPENABLED="0" /NPENABLED="0" /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled" /RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" /RSINSTALLMODE="FilesOnlyMode" /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="********" /QUIET'
              UninstallCommand='/ACTION=Uninstall /INSTANCENAME="$(var.SqlServerInstance)" /FEATURES=SQLEngine /HIDECONSOLE /QUIET'
              PerMachine='yes'
              DetectCondition='SqlInstanceFound_x86 OR SqlInstanceFound_x64'
              Id="SQLEXPR_$(var.Platform)_ENU"
              Description="SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2"
              DisplayName="SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2"
              Vital="yes"
              Protocol="none"
              LogPathVariable="SQLEXPR_$(var.Platform)_ENUFullLog"
              Compressed="yes"
              SourceFile="redist\$(var.Platform)\SQLEXPR_$(var.Platform)_ENU.exe"
              SuppressSignatureVerification="yes"/>
</PackageGroup>
```